# Why does the framework have the .h header file? I only need to make a framework for shared Swift code

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an iOS & watch app written in Swift, and I wanted to create a target for sharing code among them, preferably as a dynamic library.

I have gone to Xcode targets, hit the + sign, and picked Framework, and a new target was created with a `MyFramework.h` file with this content:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

//! Project version number for MyFramework.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double MyFrameworkVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for MyFramework.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char MyFrameworkVersionString[];

// In this header, you should import all the public headers of your framework using statements like #import <MyFramework/PublicHeader.h>
```

Why is this needed? Did I just misunderstand things, and this Framework option is just for sharing Objective-C code?

What should I do when I want to share a Swift code (and have it be a dynamic library, so that I could configure it [as a mergeable library](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-your-project-to-use-mergeable-libraries))? Create a local Swift package?

There seems to maybe be multiple meanings of the word Framework (an Objective-C - specific thing, Swift package manager unit, and a general term for extracting a common code into a shared library), and I would love to have this cleared up.